# Solve recursive equation in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I need to find such F, so that for any M $FM = MF$.
I can't figure out, how to bring this equation to the form like this: $F = TF$, so that I could just apply Y combinator

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

$$T = \lambda FM.MF$$

So

$$F = (\lambda FM. MF)F$$

Or

$$F = Y(\lambda FM. MF)$$

We can verify that this is correct using the definition of $Y$:

$$
\begin {align}
Fa &= (\lambda f.(\lambda x.f(xx))(\lambda x.f(xx)))(\lambda FM.MF)a \\
   &= (\lambda x.(\lambda FM.MF)(xx))(\lambda x.(\lambda FM.MF)(xx))a \\
   &= (\lambda xM. M(xx))(\lambda xM. M(xx))a \\
   &= a (\lambda xM. M(xx))(\lambda xM. M(xx))
\end {align}
$$

Comment: How did you come out with the trick, without using try and error?